# After trigger conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am figuring out sql script that after trigger execute if two values are already existing in tables. 
For example.

The table shows:

```
╔══════════════════════════════╗
║ User_name Question_ID Answer ║
╠══════════════════════════════╣
║     Tom       Q001        D  ║
║     Sam       Q002        F  ║
╚══════════════════════════════╝
```

If I hope that a user can submit only one answer on a question
So if I insert values ('Tom', 'Q002' 'A') 
it will successfully insert.
But if I insert values ('Tom', 'Q001' 'A')
it will execute trigger as same user tried to answer on same question.

I wrote like:

```
    Create Trigger insert_question1
    on [dbo].[Questions]
    After insert
    As
    if 
    Begin
    Print 'You already answered'
    Rollback 
    End
```

I cannot find the condition after IF 
plz help me :C

Comment: I'm sorry, but what MySQL has to do with this? Also, can't you just apply unique index to 'user_name, question_id' pair?

Comment: Im am doing my assignment and i have no clue about this. It requires me to use after trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_QUESTION1 
ON DBO.QUESTIONS 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[QUESTIONS] 
      SELECT I.[USER_NAME], 
             I.QUESTION_ID, 
             I.ANSWER 
      FROM   INSERTED I 
      WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                         FROM   QUESTIONS Q 
                         WHERE   Q.QUESTION_ID = I.QUESTION_ID 
                                AND Q.USER_NAME = I.USER_NAME) 
  END 

GO
```

This trigger will prevent a duplicate from being inserted into the table.
Do you really need the `Print 'You already answered'` ?
If yes, just add this to the end of the trigger:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  PRINT 'You already answered'
```

Comment: Thanks Gidil.
Do you have any idea of if I have to use After triger? :C

Comment: Think of this, the AFTER trigger starts executing after the insert. If you want to prevent the insert on certain conditions, you want to do this before the insert executes. Thus you need the instead of trigger.