# Conditional after trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, conditional-statements

I am required to create an after trigger. (STRICTLY AN AFTER TRIGGER ONLY). I think I am on the right track, but can't seem to get it to execute properly. It seems to always execute the trigger and show the error message on all insert statements instead of just when there is a duplicate. This is what I have;

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Copies
    ON table
    AFTER INSERT

    AS
    Declare @number int 
    Set @number = (Select Count(*) from inserted)

    If @number >0
       (
       SELECT *
       FROM table O
       JOIN inserted AS i 
       ON t.q_id = i.q_id 

       WHERE O.username = i.username 
        AND t.q_id = i.q_id
       )

    BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Already answered', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN 
    END;
    GO
```

Ps.
Please don't reply with for triggers. Thanks :)

Comment: Simple comment where is t being aliased?

Comment: Also why are you not getting an error when you try to use () to encapsulate conditional statements...Shouldn't be IF(@Number>0) BEGIN....END ELSE BEGIN rolbackcode here END

Comment: Sorry, 
    SELECT *
       FROM table O  -- this O is meant to be t
       JOIN inserted AS i
changed it in my script. no difference :/

Comment: sql server management studio

Comment: sql server management studio is not a DBMS is just an program (as smart as it is) that you use to access SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (NOT EXISTS(..code to test for existance ))
 BEGIN    
            RAISERROR ('Already answered', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN 
 END
```

Comment: Any additional ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this new trigger using `count`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Copies
ON table
AFTER INSERT

AS
DECLARE @Counter int
SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*)
FROM table T
JOIN inserted AS i 
    ON T.username = i.username 
    AND t.q_id = i.q_id
GROUP BY T.username, t.q_id 

If (@Counter > 1) 
BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Already answered', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN 
END;
GO
```

Comment: same problem, get this message even if insert statement has unique data. Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Copies, Line 19
Already answered
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: Sadly, same problem. Data is unique and still setting off trigger. :(

Comment: Do you drop and create the trigger each time?

Comment: Yes, I do it at the start of the script.

Comment: I don't know what's not working there. can you please run the third script that add bit if tracing?

Comment: Unique data: before: 1
found: 1
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Copies, Line 29
Already answered
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted. dupicated info: before: 2
found: 2
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Copies, Line 29
Already answered
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: so the row exists even before the trigger. please check that the condition is what you want to be

Comment: the requirement is too delete an insert if it already exists(and show a raiserror). I thought i did it right, if not please let me know :)

Comment: What I need to do is delete it from the table only if it already exists. So, from what I understand the trace script says it in in the table. No problems there, I just need additional scipt to remove it it already exists. :)

Comment: @james431 , I don't know what's you business logic or request. Sincerely I can't do more than answer a question that was asked. I you need to delete, why don't you do that? what's the impact to your business logic? at this moment, I don't see the point for a raiserrror.

Comment: My question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101680/sql-trigger-to-stop-duplicates-across-row and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577376/after-trigger-conditions
its just that there was no answer in these. They were after trigger, which I require.

Comment: are you going to insert many rows at a time? or just one every time? is q_id identity?

Comment: ONe row at a time, this q_id is just a column, no primary key in this table.

Comment: so what you need is a `INSTEAD OF` not an `AFTER` trigger. see my last script added. just as was suggested in your [earlier link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577376/after-trigger-conditions)

Comment: but the requirement is and AFTER trigger, that's why I'm so lost :/

Comment: This might help you help me, use SELECT COUNT(*) from inserted table joined to the questions table and compare this result to 1.

Comment: `AFTER` trigger means that it was already inserted. so there is at least one row with the keys that you are asking for. Now inside the trigger you can rollback. but you can't delete and insert a new one unless you want to start to handle trigger recursivity business logic.

Comment: I realise that, but I need to create an after trigger. I will insert data, the data will be in the table. then the after trigger will search to see if there is any instance where q.id and username match. if so, delete the newer record and display the message.

Comment: Yes! You are the greatest, don't let anyone tell you otherwise :)